# Determine value of flow

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

For a flow $\phi^t \in \mathbb{R}^m$ we know that $\phi^{-1}(A)=B,\phi^2(B)=C,\phi^{-2}(B)=A$. Determine the value of $\phi^1(C)$ or show that this flow cannot exist.

I know that flow has a group property, so $\phi^t\circ\phi^s=\phi^{t+s}$. So I know that $\phi^1(A)=C$ and $\phi^{-3}(B)=B$ but it hasn't helped me much.

Comment: Looks like $\phi (C)=B$

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so I solved it, it goes like this
$$\phi^1(C)=\phi^1(\phi^2(B))=\phi^3(B)=\phi^3(\phi^{-1}(A))=\phi^2(A)=\phi^2(\phi^{-2}(B))=\phi^0(B)=B$$